dashboard-solo tag disappeared in Grafana v11.2.0
after loading an exported panel before V11.2.0 the body tag was:
<body class="theme-dark app-grafana dashboard-solo">
in V11.2.0 the body tag is:
<body class="theme-dark app-grafana">
I used to change the style and aesthetics of the exported panel by hooking the specific tag “dashboard-solo”, while for other pages a tag is added to recognize them, for the exported ones it seems there is no longer this possibility.
It would be enough for me if the background for exported panels was always transparent.
Is there an alternative solution?

There is no promise that class names won't be changed, so this kind of hacking is very fragile - in theory it can be changed every release. So I would say use it only if you know what you are doing and you are aware of the risk.
